# python csv into dictionary

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty new to python. I need to create a class that loads csv data into a dictionary.

I want to be able to control the keys and value
So let say the following code, I can pull out worker1.name or worker1.age anytime i want.

```
class ageName(object):
'''class to represent a person'''
def __init__(self, name, age):
self.name = name
self.age = age

worker1 = ageName('jon', 40)
worker2 = ageName('lise', 22)

#Now if we print this you see that it`s stored in a dictionary
print worker1.__dict__
print worker2.__dict__
#
'''
{'age': 40, 'name': 'jon'}
#
{'age': 22, 'name': 'lise'}
#
'''
#

#when we call (key)worker1.name we are getting the (value)
print worker1.name
#
'''
#
jon
#
'''
```

But I am stuck at loading my csv data into keys and value.

[1] I want to create my own keys
worker1 = ageName([name],[age],[id],[gender])

[2] each [name],[age],[id] and [gender] comes from specific a column in a csv data file

I really do not know how to work on this. I tried many methods but I failed. I need some helps to get started on this.

---- Edit
This is my original code

```
import csv

# let us first make student an object

class Student():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fname = []
        self.lname = []
        self.ID = []
        self.sport = []
        # let us read this file
        for row in list(csv.reader(open("copy-john.csv", "rb")))[1:]:
            self.fname.append(row[0])
            self.lname.append(row[1])   
            self.ID.append(row[2])
            self.sport.append(row[3])
    def Tableformat(self):
        print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%-11s" %('First Name','Last Name','ID','Favorite Sport')
        print "-" * 45
        for (i, fname) in enumerate(self.fname):
           print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%3s" %(fname,self.lname[i],self.ID[i],self.sport[i])
    def Table(self):
        print self.lname

class Database(Student):
    def __init__(self):
        g = 0
        choice = ['Basketball','Football','Other','Baseball','Handball','Soccer','Volleyball','I do not like sport']
        data = student.sport
        k = len(student.fname)
        print k
        freq = {}
        for i in data:
            freq[i] = freq.get(i, 0) + 1
        for i in choice:
            if i not in freq:
                freq[i] = 0
            print i, freq[i]


student = Student()
database = Database()
```

This is my current code (incomplete)

```
import csv
class Student(object):
    '''class to represent a person'''
    def __init__(self, lname, fname, ID, sport):
        self.lname = lname
        self.fname = fname
        self.ID = ID
        self.sport = sport
reader = csv.reader(open('copy-john.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
student = [Student(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]) for row in reader][1::]
print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%-11s" %('First Name','Last Name','ID','Favorite Sport')
print "-" * 45
for i in range(len(student)):
    print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%3s" %(student[i].lname,student[i].fname,student[i].ID,student[i].sport)

choice = ['Basketball','Football','Other','Baseball','Handball','Soccer','Volleyball','I do not like sport']
lst = []
h = 0
k = len(student)
# 23
for i in range(len(student)):
    lst.append(student[i].sport) # merge together

for a in set(lst):
    print a, lst.count(a)

for i in set(choice):
    if i not in set(lst):
        lst.append(i)
        lst.count(i) = 0
        print lst.count(i)
```

Comment: Note that if you really want a dictionary, you can't use `worker1.name` to get the values.  Dictionaries are accessed using the form `worker1['name']`.  So, which do you really want?

Comment: Hi Peter. I am sorry and I really appreciate your comment. That's a good question. Any pro and cons? I am sorry...

Comment: There are always pros and cons, but you asked for a dictionary.  Do you mean you don't know whether you should use one or not?  To answer that, we'd need to understand more about what you're going to do with the data.

Comment: I suspect there is just some confusion due to the fact that all the instance data is stored in a dictionary belonging to the instance.

Comment: I just edited my post. You can see my original and current codes. I am creating a small program that makes STUDENT an object, with attributes like gender, name. Using Tor Valamo's code (currently) is a good idea for some of the stuff. However, as I go down to other tasks, I found myself repeatedly stating for i in range loop just to pull out the entire student.fnames, student.lnames, student.ID.

Comment: i edited my answer to show you some shortcuts of your edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('workers.csv', newline=''), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
workers = [ageName(row[0], row[1]) for row in reader]
```

workers now has a list of all the workers

```
>>> workers[0].name
'jon'
```

**added edit after question was altered**

Is there any reason you're using old style classes? I'm using new style here.

```
class Student:
    sports = []
    def __init__(self, row):
       self.lname, self.fname, self.ID, self.sport = row
       self.sports.append(self.sport)
    def get(self):
       return (self.lname, self.fname, self.ID, self.sport)

reader = csv.reader(open('copy-john.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%-11s" % tuple(reader.next()) # read header line from csv
print "-" * 45
students = list(map(Student, reader)) # read all remaining lines
for student in students:
    print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%3s" % student.get()

# Printing all sports that are specified by students
for s in set(Student.sports): # class attribute
    print s, Student.sports.count(s)

# Printing sports that are not picked 
allsports = ['Basketball','Football','Other','Baseball','Handball','Soccer','Volleyball','I do not like sport']
for s in set(allsports) - set(Student.sports):
    print s, 0
```

Hope this gives you some ideas of the power of python sequences. ;)

**edit 2, shortened as much as possible... just to show off :P**

Ladies and gentlemen, 7(.5) lines.

```
allsports = ['Basketball','Football','Other','Baseball','Handball',
             'Soccer','Volleyball','I do not like sport']
sports = []
reader = csv.reader(open('copy-john.csv'))
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num: sports.append(s[3])
    print "%-14s|%-10s|%-5s|%-11s" % tuple(s)
for s in allsports: print s, sports.count(s)
```

Comment: Wooo this is exactly what I was looking for
reader = csv.reader(open('Book.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
workers = [ageName(row[0], row[1], row[2]) for row in reader]
for i in range(len(workers)):
    print workers[i].lname, workers[i].fname, workers[i].ID

Comment: you can't define "print" as a method *and* use it as a statement on the same module.

Comment: I was thinking about it as I wrote it, and I thought it could maybe work. But I changed it now.

Comment: wooo this is cool. I am new to python so I don't know what new / old style is. I will have to to learn it over the break. Can you help me out with one more thing? Your code is great but gives two errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python26/test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    students = [Student(row) for row in reader]
  File "D:/Python26/test2.py", line 5, in __init__
    (self.lname,self.fname,self.ID,self.sport) = row
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: oh actually if i add [1::] back will give this error instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python26/test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    students = [Student(row) for row in reader[1::]]
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: I am using 2.6.4 btw, if it helps

Comment: I updated a couple of lines around where your problem is. Note that it reads the header line and prints it first, so there's no need to slice the reader (which you can't since it's an iterator, which is why you got the error).

Comment: Thank you Tor. I have a lot to learn. I will finish my program and come back to thank you and ask for more reference (how to become a very good python coder)

Comment: This code can still be improved, I just don't know if this is all you want it to do. If it is, then I can cut it by about 10 lines :P

Comment: It is what I want... 10 lines? ... omg -_- If you may, I would learn it.... hahaha Thanks

Comment: nice... Tor. I will not use the short version because it is too good. Hahaha. but please, I am very sorry to bother you. The long version has a small problem which I searched around.     for s in set(students.sports): # class attribute
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sports'.  That's it. If I can resolve this, I can implement more on my own. Again, I am really happy to have people like you to help me out... I only had two classes in python and my professor expected me to write a database program in two days... thanks

Comment: oh, that should be Student.sports

Comment: Also the last few lines were changed slightly, so make sure to update those too.

Comment: why don't you `close` the file plz? or better, use `with`?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a pretty old question, but it's impossible to read this, and not think of the amazing new(ish) Python library, `pandas`. Its main unit of analysis is a think called a DataFrame which is modelled after the way R handles data.

Let's say you have a (very silly) csv file called `example.csv` which looks like this:

```
day,fruit,sales
Monday,Banana,10
Monday,Orange,20
Tuesday,Banana,12
Tuesday,Orange,22
```

If you want to read in a csv in double-quick time, and do 'stuff' with it, you'd be hard pressed to beat the following code for either brevity or ease of use:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> csv = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
>>> csv
       day   fruit  sales
0   Monday  Banana     10
1   Monday  Orange     20
2  Tuesday  Banana     12
3  Tuesday  Orange     22
>>> csv[csv.fruit=='Banana']
       day   fruit  sales
0   Monday  Banana     10
2  Tuesday  Banana     12
>>> csv[(csv.fruit=='Banana') & (csv.day=='Monday')]
      day   fruit  sales
0  Monday  Banana     10
```

In my opinion, this is really fantastic stuff. Never iterate over a csv.reader object again!

Comment: Pretty nice. Thansk. Oh, after what? Almost 4 years! :)

Comment: This is the crazy thing about the online world: it never dies! I came across this question in a perfectly normal Googling session. Hope you check out `pandas` and enjoy it!

Answer (score 8):

I second Mark's suggestion. In particular, look at DictReader from csv module that allows reading a comma separated (or delimited in general) file as a dictionary.

Look at [PyMotW's coverage of csv module](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/csv/) for a quick reference and examples of usage of DictReader, DictWriter

Comment: I don't understand why this got a -1 without an explanatory comment. What's wrong with a suggestion to use a DictReader?

Comment: I have to say, the link you posted was quite useful =). Going to vote you up on that. (Mod's, I assuming that's ok?)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the csv module?

```
import csv
```

Comment: Yes I did. In fact I have a poorly-written version, but I realize it was a pain in the neck so I decided to do dictionary right away.