# parsing this csv file in python(pylab) and converting it into a dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I have this code:

```
 data = np.genfromtxt('csv_data.csv', dtype=None, names=True)

 print data
```

It results in the following output

```
 [('westin,390,291,70,43,19,215,27,813',)
  ('ramada,136,67,53,30,24,149,49,310',)
  ('sutton,489,293,106,39,20,299,24,947',)
  ('loden,681,134,17,5,0,199,4,837',) ('hampton,241,166,26,5,1,159,21,439',)
  ('shangrila,332,45,20,8,2,325,8,407',) ('mariott,22,15,5,0,0,179,35,42',)
  ('pan_pacific,475,262,86,29,16,249,15,868',)
  ('sheraton,277,346,150,80,26,249,45,879',)
  ('westin_bayshore,390,291,70,43,19,199,27,813',)]
```

It didn't copy the column headers:

```
  Hotel,excellent,verygood,average,poor,terrible,cheapest,rank,reviews
```

from the file. What Im trying to do is save the output to a dicationary data structure in python. Is there a way to convert this output inot a dictionary ?

I can write a function to parse this but I was wondering if there is a built in function in Python.

Thanks

Comment: Related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898305/python-csv-into-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the file yourself using the `csv` module.

The following takes the file, and creates a dictionary called `by_hotel` whose key is the hotel name, and whose values is a dictionary of fieldname->value of the original row (note it also includes the hotel name, but anyway...)

```
import csv

with open('csv_data.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.DictReader(fin)
    headers = csvin.fieldnames
    by_hotel = {row['Hotel']: row for row in csvin}

print by_hotel['sutton']['excellent']
# 489
```

If you wanted a list back in the original order, then you could do:

```
print [hotel['sutton'][fname] for fname in headers]
```

NB: You may want to convert your values to integers for computation purposes though.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give a value to the `delimiter` parameter. therefore, `np.genfromtxt` uses the default `None` and try to separate the fields using spaces.

You need to use

```
np.genfromtxt(your_file, dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple version :**

```
d = {  item[0].split(',')[0] : item[0].split(',')[1:] for item in data  }
```

return :

```
{'sutton': ['489', '293', '106', '39', '20', '299', '24', '947'], 'hampton': ['241', '166', '26', '5', '1', '159', '21', '439'], 'westin_bayshore': ['390', '291', '70', '43', '19', '199', '27', '813'], 'sheraton': ['277', '346', '150', '80', '26', '249', '45', '879'], 'ramada': ['136', '67', '53', '30', '24', '149', '49', '310'], 'mariott': ['22', '15', '5', '0', '0', '179', '35', '42'], 'loden': ['681', '134', '17', '5', '0', '199', '4', "837'"], 'shangrila': ['332', '45', '20', '8', '2', '325', '8', '407'], 'pan_pacific': ['475', '262', '86', '29', '16', '249', '15', '868']}
```

**and more complicated (dict of dict) :**

```
d = {  item[0].split(',')[0] : { headers[i] : int( item[0].split(',')[i+1].strip("'") ) for i in range(len( item[0].split(',')[1:] ) )   }  for item in data  }
```

return :

```
{'sutton': {'poor': 39, 'cheapest': 299, 'average': 106, 'terrible': 20, 'rank': 24, 'reviews': 947, 'excellent': 489, 'verygood': 293}, 'hampton': {'poor': 5, 'cheapest': 159, 'average': 26, 'terrible': 1, 'rank': 21, 'reviews': 439, 'excellent': 241, 'verygood': 166}, 'westin_bayshore': {'poor': 43, 'cheapest': 199, 'average': 70, 'terrible': 19, 'rank': 27, 'reviews': 813, 'excellent': 390, 'verygood': 291}, 'sheraton': {'poor': 80, 'cheapest': 249, 'average': 150, 'terrible': 26, 'rank': 45, 'reviews': 879, 'excellent': 277, 'verygood': 346}, 'ramada': {'poor': 30, 'cheapest': 149, 'average': 53, 'terrible': 24, 'rank': 49, 'reviews': 310, 'excellent': 136, 'verygood': 67}, 'mariott': {'poor': 0, 'cheapest': 179, 'average': 5, 'terrible': 0, 'rank': 35, 'reviews': 42, 'excellent': 22, 'verygood': 15}, 'loden': {'poor': 5, 'cheapest': 199, 'average': 17, 'terrible': 0, 'rank': 4, 'reviews': 837, 'excellent': 681, 'verygood': 134}, 'shangrila': {'poor': 8, 'cheapest': 325, 'average': 20, 'terrible': 2, 'rank': 8, 'reviews': 407, 'excellent': 332, 'verygood': 45}, 'pan_pacific': {'poor': 29, 'cheapest': 249, 'average': 86, 'terrible': 16, 'rank': 15, 'reviews': 868, 'excellent': 475, 'verygood': 262}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
f = open("csv_data",'r')
holder = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ',')
data_dict = {} 
headers = [] 
first_row = True   
for row in holder:
  if first_row:
    first_row = False
    for header in row:
      colname = str(header)
        headers.append(colname)
        data_dict[colname] = []
  else:
    colnum = 0
    for datapoint in row:
      data_dict[headers[colnum]].append(int(datapoint))
      colnum += 1
```

Thus you can have a dictionary variable having keys which are column headers(which are first row of csv file) and values associated with those keys as list(remaining data in csv file).
Moreover, header is a list of all the column headers.